# Printing a nested for-loop pattern in java

Tags: java, nested-loops

Goal:
 1234
 2345
 3456
 4567
 5678

i have the pattern down but it doesnt println after length(4):

```
    int i;
    int a;

    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) 
    {
      for (a = i;a<=i+3;a++)
      {
        System.out.print(a);
      }
    }
```

My output is: 12342345345645675678

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add it after the second loop:

```
int i;
int a;

for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  for (a = i;a<=i+3;a++) {
    System.out.print(a);
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int i;
int a;

for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) 
{
  for (a = i;a<=i+3;a++)
  {
    System.out.print(a);
  }
  System.out.println(); // add this code
{
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to have two for loops, try :

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
   int j = i;
   System.out.println(j++ + "" + j++ + "" + j++ + "" + j);
}
```

**EDIT** : I know this will limit the flexibility, but this is just a toy problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i;
int a;

for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) 
{
  for (a = i;a<=i+3;a++)
  {
    System.out.print(a);
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `System.out.println()` after the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
int i;
int a;

for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (a = i;a<=i+3;a++) {

        System.out.print(a);
    }
    System.out.println(); // this will print a new line.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `System.out.Println()` after the inner loop. This will move the cursor to next line

Answer (score 0):

**Java Solution**

```
  int f, g, h,T;
        f = 12345;
        h = 11111;
        for (g = 1; g <= 5; g++)
        {
         T = f + ((g - 1) * h);
         System.out.print(  T + "\n")
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(int i =1;i<=4;i++) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i =2;i<=5;i++) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    System.out.println();

    for(int i =3;i<=6;i++) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i =4;i<=7;i++) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: to understandable for nobbies